# KairosDB tag requirement

Tags: time-series, kairosdb, database, nosql

When inserting new data into KairosDB, why is it necessary to include a tag for every datapoint? I really only need to keep query datapoints using their metric name.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a design decision. I bet the creators of KairosDB may give you an explanation if you post the question on the KairosDB discussion group, since they are very active on it but not on Stak Overflow.

On another hand, I don't see why you wouldn't need tags, maybe your metrics would benefit for more normalization and using tags (e.g. by data source, host, ...etc.) to do useful queries.

What kind of data are you storing?